# ImageView becomes blank on Screen orientation change

Tags: android, uiimageview

I am using the below line to set my ImageView.

```
    Bitmap bm = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), capturedImage);
                    Bitmap bm1=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 300, 300,true);
                    pic.setImageBitmap(bm1);
```

But when I rotate my mobile, the imageView becomes blank. 
Can anyone help me.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I got it to work. Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191172/imageview-image-lost-on-change-in-orientation/29191883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper way to it is to save the bitmap in **onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()**

Here is an example:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: This example uses deprecated methods (getLastNonConfigurationInstance). Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831429/orientation-changes-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` to your Activity tag in your AndroidManifest.  Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should save `capturedImage` in your `onSaveInstanceState` method, and then check in your `onRestoreInstanceState` method to see if you saved it and then re-execute the code you have above. See the answer of [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state) for an excellent example of how this would work.

Comment: I tried using this. But still if I rotate my mobile for two times the image becomes null. I get the same problem. It looks persistent only for first orientation change. Is there any other way that I could try.

Comment: That really is the best way to do it: you may have an error in your implementation. If we post the code you are using in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` we might be able to point out the changes you need to make to fix the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @Lumis solution might be somewhat more efficient.