# Orientation Changes in android

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am using getLastNonConfigurationInstance() to save object while changing orientation in my activity. now it is deprecated. What is the best way of alternative? the documentation says "use Fragment". But i need to use activity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I save an activity state using the save instance state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-can-i-save-an-activity-state-using-the-save-instance-state)